# Number of Working Days between two dates[LOGIC]

Tags: mysql

I have a function is MySql which calculates the number of working dates between two given dates but I would like to know the logic that is being used in it.
The sql function is as follows:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION TOTAL_WEEKDAYS(date1 DATE, date2 DATE)
 RETURNS INT
 RETURN ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1
 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 1)
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1
 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 1)
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7)
 ;
```

`ABS` is used throughout to ensure each result is a positive integer, in case the dates are backward (*if the start point is after the end point*).

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1
```

`DATEDIFF` returns the integer number of calendar days between the **dates** of 2 datetime values (*in effect setting time to 00:00:00+00000 on both dates*). Because `DATEDIFF` uses date only the **duration** of the second day is lost, so add 1 to compensate.

```
 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2
```

Calculate the **start of the week** for both dates using `ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY)` and `ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY)` and then get the number of days between those dates. Divide that number by 7 gives the number of weeks spanned between the dates.  Multiply that number by 2 gives number of weekend days involved in the span. Subtract those weekend days from the raw number of days previously calculated gives the overall number of weekdays between the dates.

However the given start/end datetimes may individually fall on a weekend day, so:

```
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 1)
```

If one of the given dates is a Sunday, subtract 1

```
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7)
```

If one of the given dates is a Saturday, subtract 1

Resulting in the number of "workdays" where the workweek excludes Saturday & Sunday.

---

In case it is of interest, here is a query that breaks out each function or set of function calls as individual columns so you can trace each. Adjust the subquery supplying 2 dates to suit.

```
select
  date1
, date2
, DATEDIFF(date2, date1)      "datediff"
, ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) abs_datediff
, ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1 diff_2end_dt
, DAYOFWEEK(date2)                dt2_dow
, ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY) start_of_wk_dt2
, DAYOFWEEK(date1) dt1_dow
, ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY) start_of_wk_dt1
, DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY)) diff_wksby7
, ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) abs_diff_wksby7               
, ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2 diff_wkends
, DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) dow_min
, DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) dow_max

from (
    select date_add(now(), INTERVAL -34 DAY) as date1, date_add(now(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) as date2
    ) d
```

Comment: Thanks. This post really helped me understand. (Y)